# Can I travel to Sweden as a UK passport holding resident?

Tags: uk, passports, paperwork, sweden, freedom-of-movement

I'm travelling to Sweden for a few days on the 26th of November. I'm a UK resident and passport holder, will I need any other documents in order to travel?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

British Citizens (which I presume you are) [do not need a Visa, or any documentation other than a passport valid for the duration of your intended stay.](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/sweden/entry-requirements)

Moreover, as an EU citizen, your rights under [EU freedom of movement](http://ec.europa.eu/social/main.jsp?catId=457) allow you to stay for up to three months as a visitor, and as long as you wish provided you are working, or can demonstrate that you are capable of supporting yourself and will not be a burden on the host state.

It would be sensible however to also take with you at a minimum [a valid European Health Insurance Card (EHIC)](https://www.gov.uk/european-health-insurance-card), which will cover you for emergency care only in the EU, provided you are a visitor. Note that the EHIC does not cover you for many instances that actual travel insurance would.

Comment: You might want to note that EU citizens enjoy freedom of movement in the EU regardless of where they reside.

Comment: For all the questions about visa complexities from nationals of less fortunate countries, it still surprises me how unaware people are of the travel privileges their first-world citizenship gives them

Comment: @blackbird57 Dunno, I find it's more often the other way, with first-worlders being so used to travelling without a visa, that they get really confused when they have to get one/they are questioned about their intentions at the border.

Comment: That's what I meant :)

Comment: Thanks! @blackbird57 for me it's more that it's my first time leaving the UK in about 8 years, the last time being a school trip when I was 15 that was all handled for me.